# Error "Unable to parse response, not valid JSON" when using non English tags on Instagram API

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to get info about Instagram photos with cyrillic tag using Python:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from instagram import client, subscriptions
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI

api = InstagramAPI(client_id = 'XX', client_secret = 'XX')
p = api.tag_recent_media(tag_name = 'ночь')
for media in p:
    print(media)
```

It works perfectly with english tags (e.g. 'cats'), but fails with cyrillic one like here:

```
InstagramClientError: (500) Unable to parse response, not valid JSON.
```

Tried Unicode encoding\decoding and other tricks, but failed.

How to work with non-english tags?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to query the `Instagram API` with non English characters, I was able to do so.

You are getting this error probably since your request doesn't include `access_token`, you should initiate the API object like this:

```
api = client.InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token, client_secret=client_secret)
```

See more examples of using this API on [`sample_app.py`](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/blob/master/sample_app.py) in the Github repository.